# What's the story behind the name 'CiviCRM'?

Tags: civicrm.org

Last week, we finally deployed CiviCRM in our organisation. Hurray! :-)

One of the questions I get from our users, is 'what does the civi in CiviCRM means'? And I have no idea.

Does anybody knows something about the name CiviCRM, about where it comes from?

Answer (score 12):

The canonical explanation is that Civi comes from "**civi**l society", ie " "aggregate of non-governmental organizations and institutions that manifest interests and will of citizens."

Over the years, I've heard various other explanations, one is that Dave and Lobo are extremely polite borderline canadian, so when they built a crm, they wanted it **civi**l.

After the first civicon, at the end of a long night involving lots of tequila shots, I've heard a sinister plot that Dave is an 5-star general in the army that is going rogue and wants to take control of the UN. According to the legend, the [cividog](https://civicrm.org/sites/civicrm.org/files/scout.JPG) has fought back and protected the **civi**lians. Those knowing Dave (or Scout) would take that explanation with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Was it related to the "CivicSpace" drupal project?

Answer (score 3):

I have also heard the 'civic sector' alternative, but I like the Scout story far better!